# How significant is the evolution of Qt between versions 5.7 and 5.11?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to start learning Qt and found some tutorials that look good however they are for version 5.7 while the current version of Qt is 5.11. Will learning version 5.7 still teach me all the core concepts or has there been significant changes to how Qt fundamentally works (from a user perspective) within this timeframe?

Comment: There are mostly a few new classes and optimizations. Luckily, Qt 5.7 already comes with Qt Quick Controls 2, which was the last "big thing".Once you are done with the tutorials, you can read up on the changes and things that have been added [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.8) (on the bottom, you can see changes for other versions)

Comment: Qt is really almost two separate products at this point — there’s the classic QWidgets API (used for desktop apps) and thee newer Qt Quick API (used primarily for mobile apps).  The desktop API is pretty mature and hasn’t changed much between 5.7 and 5.11; the QT Quick API may have changed more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with starting from qt5.7. The bump in the minor part of the version (7->11) indicates the addition of minor features and bug fixes and no major changes.

The evolution of qt from version 5.7 to 5.11 is not significant from the perspective of someone who's trying to pick up the qt framework for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll definitely learn the basic concepts from version 5.7 tutorials too. The changes are not that fundamental. If you want to learn `Qt` you can easily install version 5.11 and use over 95 % of the version 5.7 tutorials and even older ones.